# Tinkerpop Gremlin upgrade path (3.4.10 - 3.6.5)

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have to upgrade AWS Neptune Engine version to 1.2.1.0. The current Tinkerpop gremlin version (as a client) is 3.4.10.
Now, Thought I have already upgraded the Neptune server version which is still working good with client 3.4.10.
But the recommended Max Tinkerpop version is 3.6.5 (ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-client.html).
So, here comes my challenge. I have a huge leap of version upgrade path and all I am looking for some help/assistence to know the required changes in terms of libraries/JARs upgrade.
E.g: Tinkerpop 3.6.5 requires HGraphDB version 3.2.0. Similarly, I want to know what other libraries are required to be upgraded. Of course, for other dependent libraries to upgrade or introduce freshly, it depends on whether I use it already in my other Application or not.

Comment: Is your application java-based? Do you use maven or gradle? Normally, you just bump the gremlin-driver version and have some plugin sort out the dependency conflicts after whcih you add some excludes to your dependencies (or shade some deps worst case).

Comment: Yes, I have Java based application and I use Gradle. As you mentioned, I have added the required driver version and other dependencies. But I am stuck with running graph queries on Hbase graph db and Neptune both.

Comment: So, what happens, does one work or neither? Do stacktraces say thinks like "method not found"? Are all the dependencies you specified really necessary (that is, imported in your client code)? You can start here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html

Comment: There is a specific failure I am noticing, other than that rest of the application is stable. Since I use HGraphDB as well (along with connecting to AWS Neptune), it's throwing error: `GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class io.hgraphdb.HBaseGraph]`.

Comment: OK, more of the stacktrace is needed to see where library conflicts occur, if at all.